# Deploy application fails on weblogic 12c

Tags: java, web-services, soap, weblogic12c, webservice-client

We have Java webservices application (SOAP) which developed with  java 1.6 and deployed in weblogic 9 and it works fine ,Now we upgrade java 1.8 and weblogic 12c we are facing below errors

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:123)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:114)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:207)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

The the WebService application  is using the wsdlLocation attribute for @WebServiceClient annotation.

Comment: It sounds like a security or network issue. Can you provide the complete error log showing this issue ?

Comment: Hi @EmmanuelCollin,  We  deployed the application in Production Server(Where there is not internet communication ) so when it validations Annotations which consists  of URL it throws the connection refuse error

Comment: post the log please ; we could see which file weblogic is trying to read from internet.

Comment: try to download the wsdl file, save it to your file system and update your annotation to set the path of the wsdl file.

Comment: Hi @EmmanuelCollin if i set the path,It will take Local path(WSDL Location="http:local host: 8081//example.org/complex",) but this application should deploy in many servers ,So if i set the local path it wont work for remaining servers !!

Comment: So any workaround we have to do in weblogic 12c..? to ignore the @annotation  WSDL location because in weblogic 10 it ignore